# Custom content scroll box's scroll bar jumps on drag

Tags: javascript

I created a custom content scroll box using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. When you try to drag the scrollbar it jumps to the left edge of the scrollbar. Any idea why am I missing something?

```
var scrollbar = document.getElementById("scrollbar");
var barWidth = 300;
var scrollbarWidth = 40;

scrollbar.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", hScroll, null);
}, null)

window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", hScroll, null);
}, null);

function hScroll(e) {
    var scroller_pos = e.clientX - offset;
    if (scroller_pos <= 0) scroller_pos = 0;
    else if (scroller_pos >= barWidth-scrollbarWidth) scroller_pos = barWidth-scrollbarWidth;
    scrollbar.style.marginLeft = scroller_pos + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mousedown you should calculate the offset between the distance of the square from the `bar`'s left edge and the distance of the mouse x position from the same edge. Then on move you should add this to the new position of the square.

```
 _____
|     |
|   .<+--click
|___|_|
|<->|
  |
offset
```

Comment: Thanks for that :-) what about the random jumps and not scrolling to the end of each side.

Comment: This should fix it too. When you click on the square it is in random position, but you're calculating the left margin absolute to the mouse pointer so the square jumps to the right and you're not able do drag it to the correct position.

Comment: Thanks never thought of that. "e.offsetX" solved it working solution link : http://jsfiddle.net/YVxf3/